# Отсортировать массив дат по близости к дате

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, сортировка

Нужно отсортировать события по дате их наступления.

**Пример**

Пусть сегодня 10.12.2020, а изначальный массив равен:

```
givenArray = [ '18.12.2020', '12.12.2020', '18.12.2019', '10.12.2020', '15.12.2020']
```

Тогда отсортированный массив это:

```
sortedArray = ['10.12.2020', '12.12.2020', '15.12.2020', '18.12.2020', '18.12.2019']
```

**Мой алгоритм не работает**

```js
let a = [ '18.12.2020', '12.12.2020', '18.12.2019', '10.12.2020', '15.12.2020'];
const b = new Date();
a.sort(val => b.getFullYear() - Number(val.slice(4, 8)));
a.sort(val => b.getMonth() - Number(val.slice(2, 4)));
a.sort(val => b.getDate() - Number(val.slice(0, 2)));
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Попробуйте сказать словами, что делает Ваш код, и Вы поймете, почему он не может "работать".

Comment: то есть вам надо 1) Перевести строку в дату 2) вычислить разницу между текущим днем и остальными датами 3) Отсортировать даты по этой разнице

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так.

1. Приводим к Date
2. Сортируем
3. Разбиваем на даты до текущего дня и после либо равно.
4. Даты после или равны идут первыми, затем те что прошли. (При необходимости вторые можно отсортировать.)
5. Объединяем.
6. Выводим в исходном формате.

```js
Number.prototype.pad = function(size) {
var s = String(this);
while (s.length < (size || 2)) {s = "0" + s;}
return s;
}


let a = ["07.12.2020", "05.12.2020", "03.12.2020", "08.12.2019", "02.12.2019", "20.12.2020"];
const today = new Date();
let s = a.map(val => new Date(val.slice(6, 10)+"-"+val.slice(3, 5)+"-"+val.slice(0, 2))).sort((a,b)=> a - b);
let result = [...s.filter(i => i >= today),...s.filter(i => i < today).reverse()].map(i=>i.getDate().pad() + "." + (i.getMonth() + 1).pad() + "." + i.getFullYear());
 

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Код не работает для `["07.12.2020", "05.12.2020", "03.12.2020", "08.12.2019", "02.12.2019", "20.12.2020"]`

Comment: Сейчас исправим терпение

Comment: Так лучше думаю?

Answer (score 0):

можно обойтись малой кровью :)

ну относительно малой - если массивы не мегабайтные

1. отсортировать массив
2. дату преобразовать к виду год-месяц-день
3. сортировать как строку

если что - то дату в виде год-месяц-день можно перевести в timestamp и сортировать как числа

```js
arr = ['18.12.2020', '12.12.2020', '18.12.2019', '10.12.2020', '15.12.2020'];

arr = arr.sort((data1, data2) => data1.split('.').reverse().join('-').localeCompare(data2.split('.').reverse().join('-')) > 0 ? 1 : -1);

console.log(arr);
```

Понял, что требовал автор - вот решение:

```js
    arr = ['18.12.2020', '12.12.2020', '18.12.2019', '10.12.2020', '15.12.2020'];
    
    arr = arr.sort((data1, data2) => {
      obj1 = data1.split('.').map(str => parseInt(str))
      obj2 = data2.split('.').map(str => parseInt(str))
      
      if (obj1[1] == obj2[1])
        if (obj1[0] == obj2[0])
          return (obj2[2] - obj1[2])
        else    
          return (obj1[0] - obj2[0])
      else
        return (obj1[1] - obj2[1])
    });
    
    console.log(arr);
```

Comment: `"18.12.2019",` должно быть последним. Сортировка же по разности между текущей датой и датами из списка.

Comment: ну просто знак изменить в функции сортировки

Comment: не получится так, поглядите как выголядит отсортированный массив в самом вопросе.

Comment: Ну думаю я правильно понял :))

Comment: т.е. надо день месяц по возрастанию, а год по убыванию? тогда через через split разрываем  и переводим в числа и сравниваем согласно данного условия

Comment: Не месяц а дату то что прийдёт по возрастанию и то что прошло в конец

Comment: сделал требуемый вывод, если я правильно понял что нужно

Comment: Не будет работать тут [
  "12.01.2021",
  "10.12.2020",
  "15.12.2020",
  "18.12.2020",
  "18.12.2019"
]

Comment: тогда я значит совершенно не понял что значит "отсортировать по дате наступления события" + приложение примра